# Shell Script Unexpected End of File

Tags: shell

**How this works?**
sorry i am beginner and find not any tutorial or website to explain this things.
When you knowing how find this please tell me, im realy appreciated that.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Blur
clear


echo "Rangcheck" 

if grep -w $name ./rangs/exo_users.txt; 
then
    echo "Blur" > "./status/rang.txt"
    ./menu.sh
else
if grep -w $name ./rangs/police_users.txt; 
then
    echo "Police" > "./status/rang.txt"
    ./menu.sh
else
if grep -w $name ./rangs/bank_users.txt; 
then
    echo "Bank" > "./status/rang.txt"
    ./menu.sh
else
if grep -w $name ./rangs/fly_users.txt; 
then
    echo "Fly" > "./status/rang.txt"
    ./menu.sh
else
if grep -w $name ./rangs/userlist.txt; 
then
    echo "User" > "./status/rang.txt"
    ./menu.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `else`..`if`, use `elif`, and make sure to terminate `if` expressions with `fi`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Blur
clear


echo "Rangcheck" 

if grep -w "$name" ./rangs/exo_users.txt; 
then
    echo "Blur" > "./status/rang.txt"
    ./menu.sh
elif grep -w "$name" ./rangs/police_users.txt; 
then
    echo "Police" > "./status/rang.txt"
    ./menu.sh
elif grep -w "$name" ./rangs/bank_users.txt; 
then
    echo "Bank" > "./status/rang.txt"
    ./menu.sh
fi
```

Also try [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), where you can paste your script to have issues like this pointed out automatically.